# importing sbt scala project to intellij idea takes long time

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to create a scala sbt project for first time on windows 10 with intellij idea, first problem was "cannot run program powershell.exe" and after searching in Stackoverflow I solved it (by uncheck sbt sources in intellij setting). now after 3 hours intellij cannot import sbt project and just say "importing sbt project". it's take long time , how can I solve this problem? I cant find solution on the web, and syncing project takes long long time. please help me.

Comment: Are you required to use sbt?

Comment: I want to use kafka and spark and I dont know any way to do this. please help me. my deadline is going to be over.

Comment: That's fine. But Maven and Gradle work just as well as sbt (sbt is slow overall). Giving arbitrary deadlines to internet strangers doesn't make the answer come faster, btw

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and it was so so suffering :))
I can solve this problem in this way:
first I add **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0** to my System path in environment variables in windows 10, after that I restart my Pc, after restarting I create a new scala sbt project but I choose scala version 2.11 and sbt version 0.0.3x instead of 1.x.x
and It worked ,
wish you best !

Comment: Scala doesn't have a version 11.10. You should really use Scala 2.12.x, anyway